# Is it possible to calculate a square root of an unknown number using only basic arithmetics?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, radicals

Long story short: Trying to implement calculation of distance between 2 points using the formula:

$$z = \sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2- y_1)^2}$$

Is there a way to calculate $Z$ with only basic arithmetic functions? $X$ and $Y$ coordinates are positive integers on a 2D map.

Comment: How to do this used to be taught in schools. Around 1970 or so, calculators caused people to start neglecting this.

Comment: Assuming the distances involved are small, a Maclaurin series could work.

Comment: No there isn't, if I have understood your question. I assume that your "basic arithmetic functions" consist of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division?

Comment: Use the average and divide method.

Comment: You can get a close approximation using [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method).

Comment: A description of the classic square root algorithm can be found [here](https://www.basic-mathematics.com/square-root-algorithm.html).

Comment: @Karl That involves calculus, though.

Comment: @JohnDouma To get an approximation, sure, but to find that the approximation is valid, you need calculus, and if you want the exact value, you need limits.

Comment: I don't even know how to calculate the *square* of an "unknown" number.

Comment: @Angel : You NEED calculus for that? Calculus may be sufficient for the task, but you seem to say calculus is _necessary_ for the task, which would mean there's no other way to do it.

Comment: Looks like you are in the wrong SE, my guess is you are trying to implement collision detection and that is why you are looking for cheap ways of calculating, is that correct?

Comment: @jimjim Trying to calculate the time it would take to move from and to specific coordinates on a map. Hence needing to calculate the distance between 2 points.

Comment: It  is strange way of going about this , not sure what has created such constraints , if you could explain why can only use simple arithmetic for this task maybe another alternative can be suggested , @f-g-rollet

Comment: @jimjim it's for an rpg project using RPG maker. Working with variables, there is only simple arithmetic operations available. I suppose there could be a way to script/program it, but that's beyond my abilities :(

Comment: In that case you might want to use a different distance measure , like taxicab metric . Then no need for complex arithmetic.

Comment: @jimjim That sounds like a perfect work around ! Thanks :)

Comment: @MichaelHardy Apologies for the late reply. Yes, you *need* calculus for that. Maclaurin series are defined via limits, and there is no other way to define them. And if you are using limits, then you are using calculus.

Comment: @Angel See my answer below. Also, you cannot get the exact value, as a decimal, for $\sqrt{2}$ because it is an irrational number. We can only compute it to a specified precision.

Comment: @JohnDouma  *Also, you cannot get the exact value, as a decimal, for $\sqrt2$ because it is an irrational number.* This is an ignorant claim. The phrase "exact value" merely refers for an expression that is exactly equal to a quantity, and does not merely approximate it. It has nothing to do with its decimal representation. I never claimed you can provide a terminating decimal representation of $\sqrt2.$ This is also not relevant to anything I have said here. $\sqrt2$ can be approximated by a rational number to arbitrary precision, and this can be done using the Newton-Rhapshon method, or...

Comment: @JohnDouma ...or its continued fraction expansion, by way of convergents. But reproducing the continued fraction expansion involves calculus as well. Infinite series are also options, where you can either use the entire series for an exact expression, or you can truncate the series for an increasing accurate rational approximation. But again, series use calculus. Everything in approximation theory and numerical methods relies in calculus. This is why everyone learns calculus before either.

Comment: @JohnDouma Also, I saw your answer below, and it does not disprove anything I have said here. You presenting an iterative method. Iterative methods are all derived using calculus, and come from calculus, and this one in particular, the average-and-divide method, is a special case obtained by substituting $f(x)=x^2-2$ in this case.

Comment: @Angel This method was not derived using calculus. You can define the sine function using power series but that does not mean you need power series to define the sine function. I learned the below method in the eighth grade, long before I learned calculus.

Answer (score 2):

You only need addition and division to compute the square root of a number. The method I will demonstrate is called Average and Divide and can be taught to an elementary school student.

As an example, we will compute $\sqrt{5}$.

1. Guess at a solution. I will guess $2$. If your guess is way off, you will still get the right answer.
2. Divide your guess into the number whose square root you are calculating. For this example, we get $5\div 2=2.5$
3. Take the average of the result of step $2$ and your last guess to get $\frac{2+2.5}{2}=2.25$
4. Return to step $1$ using our new value, $2.25$ as a guess. Continue these steps until the number you divide into $5$ is the same, up to the precision you seek, as the result of the division.

For this case, the sequence of guesses we get are $$2, 2.25, 2.236$$

You can check that $(2.236)^2=4.999696$. If you need more precision you just keep repeating the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean is there a formula in terms of (a finite number) of arithmetic operations that will produce the square root, than the answer is no. If the numbers $x_i$ and $y_i$ are rational numbers, then any formula using only arithmetic operations will (if well defined) have as value a rational number. But the desired square root can very well not be a rational number in this case.